# Jquery reset animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation

im making a slideshow with a couple different effect. This particular effect sizes the image down and fades out. But the problem is, I need the image to be reset to its original state so when the users clicks back to that image, it doesent still have the opacity of "0.2". Anyway I can reset the animation after its done?

```
if (currentEffect == "glimpse") {
 $("#next").click(function() {
   if (currentSlide == 0) {
    $("#slide1").animate({
     width: "0",
     opacity: 0.2,
     borderWidth: "10px"
    }, 1000 );
    $("#slide2").fadeIn(800);
   }
 });
}
```

Comment: How can you even see the image if you're setting the width to zero?

Answer (score 0):

`.animate()` has a callback for when its completed: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

just use that to reset it.

```
$("#slide1").animate({
     width: "0",
     opacity: 0.2,
     borderWidth: "10px"
    }, 1000, function(){ 
      //reset the image's opacity, width, etc.
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the style attribute after animation complete.

Like above solution:

```
$("#slide1").animate({
 width: "0",
 opacity: 0.2,
 borderWidth: "10px"
}, 1000, function(){ 
  $('#slide1').removeAttr('style');
});
```